# SQL JOIN that uses OR in the ON statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I’m running a SQL query on Google BigQuery and want to do this kind of SQL command:

```
SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B
ON A.col1=B.col1 AND (A.col2=B.col2 OR A.col3=B.col3)
```

This fails though with the error:

```
Error: ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each table, with all field names prefixed with table name.
```

Is there a way to rewrite the SQL to get this kind of functionality?

Comment: even in regular SQl I woudl not write this statment as it would be a performance killer. CAn you wirte a UNION All statment in bigquery? That is how I woudl handle it in SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this works, which is equivalent to a UNION ALL statement in Google BigQuery. Not sure how to do it if you just want a UNION, since DISTINCT is actually not supported in BigQuery. Luckily it's enough for me as is.

```
SELECT ... FROM 

(SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B ON A.col1=B.col1 AND A.col2=B.col2),
(SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B ON A.col1=B.col1 AND A.col3=B.col3)
```

Comment: for a DISTINCT equivalent you can use GROUP [EACH] BY

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT ... FROM A CROSS JOIN B
WHERE A.col1=B.col1 AND (A.col2=B.col2 OR A.col3=B.col3)
```

Comment: CROSS JOIN cannot have ON clause: 4.1 - 4.9

Comment: Cross join can have scaling issues, but if you use a join on the first clause you can keep the or as a where clause. That is: `SELECT ... FROM A JOIN B
ON A.col1=B.col1 WHERE (A.col2=B.col2 OR A.col3=B.col3)`